# How to log the program flow of a very deep and complex functional JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, console.log, reselect

I'm trying to understand the flow of the functions in this [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect/blob/master/src/index.js) library. I currently use `console.log` to log the output. Still, it is hard to understand the flow. Make me think how complex functional programming is!!!

How can I intercept the calls and log the function name and the parameters to the console with ES6 decorator or Proxy or any other language features?

```js
function defaultEqualityCheck(a, b) {
  return a === b
}

function areArgumentsShallowlyEqual(equalityCheck, prev, next) {
  if (prev === null || next === null || prev.length !== next.length) {
    return false
  }

  // Do this in a for loop (and not a `forEach` or an `every`) so we can determine equality as fast as possible.
  const length = prev.length
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (!equalityCheck(prev[i], next[i])) {
      return false
    }
  }

  return true
}

function defaultMemoize(func, equalityCheck = defaultEqualityCheck) {
  
  let lastArgs = null
  let lastResult = null
  
  console.log("Entering defaultMemoize");
  
  console.log("###INPUT### defaultMemoize argument func type: " + typeof func);
  
  // we reference arguments instead of spreading them for performance reasons
  return function () {
    
    if (!areArgumentsShallowlyEqual(equalityCheck, lastArgs, arguments)) {
      
      // apply arguments instead of spreading for performance.
      lastResult = func.apply(null, arguments)
    }

    lastArgs = arguments
    
    return lastResult
  }
}

function getDependencies(funcs) {
  const dependencies = Array.isArray(funcs[0]) ? funcs[0] : funcs

  if (!dependencies.every(dep => typeof dep === 'function')) {
    const dependencyTypes = dependencies.map(
      dep => typeof dep
    ).join(', ')
    throw new Error(
      'Selector creators expect all input-selectors to be functions, ' +
      `instead received the following types: [${dependencyTypes}]`
    )
  }

  return dependencies
}

function createSelectorCreator(memoize, ...memoizeOptions) {
  
  console.log("Entering createSelectorCreator");
  
  console.log("#INPUT# argument memoize name: " + memoize.name);

  console.log("#INPUT# argument memoize options: ");
  
  console.log(memoizeOptions);

  return (...funcs) => {
    
    let recomputations = 0
    
    const resultFunc = funcs.pop()
    const dependencies = getDependencies(funcs)

    console.log("##INPUT## argument funcs: ");
    console.log(resultFunc);
    
    const memoizedResultFunc = memoize(
      function () {
        recomputations++
        
        // apply arguments instead of spreading for performance.
        return resultFunc.apply(null, arguments)
      },
      ...memoizeOptions
    )
    
    console.log("memoizedResultFunc: " + typeof memoizedResultFunc);

    // If a selector is called with the exact same arguments we don't need to traverse our dependencies again.
    const selector = defaultMemoize(function () {
      const params = []
      const length = dependencies.length

      if (arguments != null)
      {
        console.log("***INPUT*** arguments: ");
        console.log(arguments);
      }
      
      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        // apply arguments instead of spreading and mutate a local list of params for performance.
        params.push(dependencies[i].apply(null, arguments))
      }

      // apply arguments instead of spreading for performance.
      return memoizedResultFunc.apply(null, params)
    })

    selector.resultFunc = resultFunc
    selector.recomputations = () => recomputations
    selector.resetRecomputations = () => recomputations = 0
    
    return selector
  }
}

const createSelector = createSelectorCreator(defaultMemoize)

function createStructuredSelector(selectors, selectorCreator = createSelector) {
  if (typeof selectors !== 'object') {
    throw new Error(
      'createStructuredSelector expects first argument to be an object ' +
      `where each property is a selector, instead received a ${typeof selectors}`
    )
  }
  const objectKeys = Object.keys(selectors)
  return selectorCreator(
    objectKeys.map(key => selectors[key]),
    (...values) => {
      return values.reduce((composition, value, index) => {
        composition[objectKeys[index]] = value
        return composition
      }, {})
    }
  )
}

const shopItemsSelector = state => state.shop.items
const taxPercentSelector = state => state.shop.taxPercent

const subtotalSelector = createSelector(
  shopItemsSelector,
  items => items.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0)
)

const taxSelector = createSelector(
  subtotalSelector,
  taxPercentSelector,
  (subtotal, taxPercent) => subtotal * (taxPercent / 100)
)

const totalSelector = createSelector(
  subtotalSelector,
  taxSelector,
  (subtotal, tax) => ({ total: subtotal + tax })
)

let exampleState = {
  shop: {
    taxPercent: 8,
    items: [
      { name: 'apple', value: 1.20 },
      { name: 'orange', value: 0.95 },
    ]
  }
}

console.log(subtotalSelector(exampleState))// 2.15
//console.log(taxSelector(exampleState))// 0.172
//console.log(totalSelector(exampleState))// { total: 2.322 }
```

Comment: `Function#bind` and `arguments` aren't new, and aren't related to logging. How do you think they might help?

Comment: As I understand, ```bind``` was (introduced in 2011)[http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5]. I have experience with JavaScript with the previous versions only, and also primarily with libraries like ```JQuery```. I'm trying ```console.log``` variables to the console to study the flow.

Comment: `bind` is from ES5 (2009), and I think `arguments` has been around since JavaScript day 1 in 1995. Neither are exactly recent, given the way the language is evolving at the moment :-)